# Improving Solr Search Query / Filter

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to Solr, but looking to use it as part of my site for indexing ingredients.

I'm looking for advice to improve the query below. I've tried NGram filtering but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why 'red onion' would score more highly than 'red pepper' ? It makes no sense to me.  Ideally a user would search for 'red onion' or 'red onions' and these would score higher.

any advice would be appreciated! I have already tried porterstemming filters, and ngram filtering, but these don't seem to have any effect.

[image]

Comment: Update.. I was implementing the Ngram tokenizer wrong, however it's  still not really helping

Comment: Your query doesn't search for `red onion` in name, it searches for `red` in `name` and `onion` in the default search field (which usually is `_text_` - but you might not have any copyField rules that populate the field). So in your case - you might just be getting hits because of the `red` part of your query and not the `onion` part. Since all the scores are identical, that seems to be the case. You can try `name:red name:onion` to see if the theory holds. You might want to use the `edismax` query handler with `q=red onion&qf=name` instead, or use `q=red onion&df=name` to set the default field

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go for exact match here. To achieve the same please apply the string field type to your field as below.

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" />
```

I have indexed data as below.

```
{
"id":"1",
"name" : "red onion"
},
{
"id":"2",
"name" : "red pepper"
},
{
"id":"3",
"name" : "red cabbage"
},
{
"id":"4",
"name" : "red chilli"
}
```

when I search for the name:red onion, I get red onion on top. Please refer the below solr query screen for the same.

[image: Screen]

The screenshot with score and debugQuery is on.

[image]

Comment: The problem is I need fuzzy matching, so if someone searched for "red onions" it would still need to match better than red pepper

Comment: You can use 2 fields in this case. One with string type and other of the text_general type. Search on both the fields. Give higher boosting to the field with string type

Comment: You can think of using edismax here. It will allow you to apply boosts to each field, meaning that hits in  exact_match_name will be scored higher than in name. example exact_match_name:game^10 name:game^5

Comment: Hi Abhijit thanks for your help. The problem is, the search query is dynamic and I do not know what the search query will be - therefore I cannot boost different words.

I need the user for instance to search for 'red onions'

And 'red onion' to be the top hit, not red pepper, as it is now

Comment: we are not boosting the search words/terms..rather we will be boosting the fields where search will be performed hence will get more relevant results on the top as per your requirement

Comment: I would suggest run the search query with &debugQuery=on...this will provide how scoring is calculated for better understanding

Comment: thank you for your help. I don't know if your on PPH and could do some consultancy?